# Date() returns a year in future instead of correct year

Tags: php, timestamp

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s','1345453380000');` should return `2012-08-20 09:03:00` but instead it returns `44605-09-21 02:00:00`

I understand the time difference of one day may be due to me not specifically setting timezone in the conversion, but 38k years in the future is a bit off, where am I doing it wrong?
Is it the trailing zeros?

I appreciate any pointers... (BTW That timestamp is how certain apps deliver them, I did not craft it myself)

When I `getdate()` that same timestamp the same issue happens, so I don't think my code is wrong, rather something is problematic with the trailing 0's...
But even if I use the from human to timestamp converted, with epoch converter, I get wrong results.

ONLY if I remove ALL zeros it seems to return a proper date.
Why?

Note again, the timestamp is how it comes from an online "diary" App, and Epoch converter IS able to read it!
(https://www.epochconverter.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening here is that the timestamp is in milliseconds, but PHP expects seconds. Epoch converter works fine with both seconds and milliseconds. What you have to do is call `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', ($timestamp/1000));`

Look at [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d5b7da3bd816f067aaeb6e913d28012d64f0feb) demo.

Answer (score 1):

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s',(1345453380000/1000));
```

Above code converts milliseconds to seconds.